# HTML Navigation bar sometimes broken in IE (tested in IE8, 9, and 10)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a navigation bar at the top of my webpage that does not always display properly in IE. The navigation bar always looks fine in Chrome and FireFox.

While using IE, if I hit the back button, refresh the page, or visit the page a 2nd time the navigation menu hover stops working properly. However, if I delete my browser history and visit the page again it works like it should, but only until I do one of the aforementioned actions again.

I've tried disabling caching but the problem persists with cashing turned off as well. When IE stops showing my drop down items the header keeps all of its other css formatting, (still orange, still in the upper left hand corner, still frustrating).

However, I have noticed that when I am in developer mode I stop having this issue. As long as I keep developer mode open (not running) the header works correctly the entire time. As soon as I close developer mode the header resumes being broken.

I can't expect everyone to turn on developer mode just to view my webpage, any help here is appreciated.

header.css

```
    /* Main menu settings */
#header {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; /* Menu font */
    font-size:90%; /* Menu text size */
    z-index:1000; /* This makes the dropdown menus appear above the page content below */
}
/* Top menu items */
#header ul {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color: #ff7f26;
}
#header ul li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
#header ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:.6em .5em .4em;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1em;
    background:#ff7f26;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#header ul li.active a {
    color:#fff;
    background:#ff7f26;
}
#header ul li a:hover {
    background:#ff7f26; /* Top menu items background colour */
    color:#fff;
}
#header ul li:hover a,
#header ul li.hover a { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
    background:#ff7f26; /* Top menu items background colour */
    color:#fff;
}
/* Submenu items */
#header ul ul {
    display:none; /* Sub menus are hidden by default */
    position:absolute;
    top:1.9em;
    left:0;
    float:left;
    right:auto; /*resets the right:50% on the parent ul */
    width:10em; /* width of the drop-down menus */
}
#header ul ul li {
    left:auto;  /*resets the left:50% on the parent li */
    margin:0; /* Reset the 1px margin from the top menu */
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#header ul ul li a,
#header ul li.active li a,
#header ul li:hover ul li a,
#header ul li.hover ul li a { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
    font-size:.8em;
    font-weight:normal; /* resets the bold set for the top level menu items */
    background:#ff7f26;
    color:black;
    line-height:1.4em; /* overwrite line-height value from top menu */
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#header ul ul li a:hover,
#header ul li.active ul li a:hover,
#header ul li:hover ul li a:hover,
#header ul li.hover ul li a:hover { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
    background:#36f; /* Sub menu items background colour */
    color:#fff;
    float:left;
}
/* Flip the last submenu so it stays within the page */
#header ul ul.last {
    left:auto; /* reset left:0; value */
    right:0; /* Set right value instead */
}
#header ul ul.last li {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    right:.8em;
}
/* Make the sub menus appear on hover */
#header ul li:hover ul,
#header ul li.hover ul { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
    display:block; /* Show the sub menus */
}
```

header.htm

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://support/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a>
            <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="//support/supportsite/errorlog/">Error Log</a></li>
                <li><a href="//support/supportsite/blslog/">Transmission Log</a></li>
                <li><a href="//support/info">Info</a></li>
            </ul></nav></li>
        <li><a href="#">Query</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="//support/query/audit">Audit</a></li>
                <li><a href="//support/query/statistics">Statistics</a></li>
                <li><a href="//support/query/monitor/">Monitor</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Admin</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="//support/admin/tools">Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="//support/admin/resources">Resources</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Troubleshooting</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="//support/troubleshooting/troubleshootinglinks">Troubleshooting Links</a></li>
                <li><a target=_blank href="https://trouble1/monitor/">Monitor 1</a></li>
                <li><a target=_blank href="https://trouble2/monitor/">Monitor 2</a></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

default.htm

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="header.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.htm");
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no need to re-declare a `<!DOCTYPE html>` in `header.htm` It's already declared in `default.htm`. Nor should you be including any CSS in `header.htm` (Eg. `<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="//support/css/header.css">`). Move that to `default.htm`. And why the double-slashes in all your URLs? Eg. `//support/query/audit`?

Comment: Thank you! Moving the css call to default.htm fixed that issue.

I'm not familiar with web hosting, I have all the double-slashes because

Comment: Thank you! Moving the css call to default.htm fixed that issue. However, when I navigate to an .asp page the header doesn't look right anymore. It looks like its losing most of the css properties (its about 10px away from the top and left border). It kept its color but the drop downs aren't working again.

Of course it works in Chrome and FireFox though.

I'm not familiar with web hosting, I have all the double-slashes because the header.htm and header.css files are in one location and I'd like every page to be able to retrieve it no matter when the user navigates to. (easier editing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! Moving the css call to default.htm fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code:

```
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="//support/css/header.css">
```

to :

```
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="header.css">
```

Initially, you were referring to non existing css file i.e (//support/css/header.css) and the correct reference is :
`<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="header.css">` ,meaning you are now referring to  local css file which is in existence.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: I tried it this way as well. This was half the trick. I needed to move my link to the css to default.htm rather than having it in the header.htm.